# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 22): The long and the short of it

Tags: word, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](/q/124765/) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](/q/124806/)</sub>

---

The following words can be paired and each pair associated with two letters. The pairs of letters can be arranged to make a single word. What is the word?

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BREAD | ELEMENT | ERGO | FIFTY-EIGHT |
| HENCE | JAM | LIGHT | SECOND |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is

> SOLSTICE,
>  which is especially appropriate for this season! Although in my time zone the solstice was last night, rather than today :)

> ERGO and HENCE are both synonyms of SO

> LIGHTSECOND is abbreviated LS

> TI is "a drink with JAM and BREAD" in [The Sound of Music](https://youtu.be/drnBMAEA3AM?si=zkdBv287R31y7iqv)

> CE, cerium, is ELEMENT FIFTY-EIGHT

The puzzle's title refers to

> the summer solstice and winter solstice, respectively the longest and shortest days (time from sunup to sundown) of the year.

Comment: Exactly so and I will take it as read that you understand the name of the puzzle.

Comment: Yes, but I'll add a comment about it. Thanks for the puzzle!